# Отправка email с сайта клиентским скриптом

Tags: рассылка, веб-программирование, php, html, javascript

в последнее время я часто замечаю, как при отправке формы на сторонних сайтах, форма отправляется не перезодя на другие страницы/скрипты.

другими словами:

1. зашел на сайт
2. ввел данные
3. нажал на кномпку "отправить"
4. выскочило информирующее окошко "данные отправлены" БЕЗ ПЕРЕХОДА НА
       ДР. СТРАНЦЫ. все действия на одной

как это реализовать?
спасибо!

Comment: Делается XMLHttpRequest и выводится сообщение.

Comment: Такое ощущение что Вы лет на 5 отстали)

Comment: да, я и правда сто лет не занимался веб-разработкой)

Answer (score 1):

Это возможно сделать с помощью AJAX.

В этом примере: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/SbxHT/ в поле где JS закоментированы строчки для PHP скрипта который примет информацию и отправит в файл\на почту.

Comment: Этот код, это AJAX ?
Он будет работать на обычных серверах кот поддерживают PHP и только?
Или это сродни JavaScript?

$('#feedback div').click(function(){
    $('#feedback ul').toggle(300);
});
$('#feedback a').click(function(){ 
    var kx='name='+$('#feedback input[name=fname]').val()+'&phone='+$('#feedback input[name=phone]').val();
    // передаём в $_POST на feedback.php
 $.ajax({
  url: 'feedback.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'html',
  data: kx
 });    
    $('#feedback ul').toggle(300);
    return false;
});

Comment: Пошло, jquery а может ему не надо jquery подключать?

Comment: jQuery это JavaScript и он работает на клиенте а не на сервере. А пойдёт любой севрер с PHP.

Comment: Так, все сделал, почему то не равботает... Вот код, подскажите пожалуйста, где допустил ошибку?
Вот код index.php Ничего не менял:
к сожалению кол-во символов ограничено, поэтому вот фото: 
http://gyazo.com/5cde19417c4e932bf88c94796ea17bcb.png

А вот что я поменял, так это feedback.php
Но он рабочий, 100%. он и сейчас у меня на сайте работает, все нормально
http://gyazo.com/62081888bac4ae278e4bcd0eb5cbfa7d.png

в чем ошибка то?)

Comment: Оберните код в:

$(document).ready(function(){

  // тут код из примера

});

и проверьте консоль, на вид всё работает верно.

Comment: а на сколько этот метод кроссбраузерный? и на сколько вероятность и действенность отправки письма ниже, чем при обычном старом методе?